# Finder Gallery view showing images much smaller than available area

Tags: mac, finder, image-gallery

How do I increase the size of the selected photo in Gallery view within Finder on a Mac?

See attached image as example. The image is only taking up about a third of available space. Both sidebars are small leave plenty of room on the sides. There is also plenty of room at the top and bottom.

I'm not talking about the icons which have a view option for small/medium/large. I'm talking about the selected file's image in the center.

The attached example has a photo that's 6048x4024, so it's certainly not an issue with resolution.

I see the same behavior with jpg and nef files, so it doesn't seem to be file type either.

[image]

Comment: Odd. Mine fill the space [even if they're small] btw, using that naming scheme, what do you do once you've taken 10k photos? ;)) I use DSC, DSD, DSE etc.. Checked  Mojave & Monterey, can't repro.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have a lot more than 10k photos. I take about 1k photos per hour when I'm shooting. So 3k-4k per photo shoot. They're in lots of separate folders in well defined hierarchies though. The exports also get renamed upon export. Thanks for the tip though; it would be well headed if I wasn't already organizing them. Plus it's important to retain the original picture number since I end up with `nef`, `psd`, and multiple `jpg` versions of the ones I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

I found out the cause but not a full solution.

The problem is Dropbox. When a file is online-only the Dropbox plugin will allow a preview in Finder even though the file is actually a zero-byte placeholder (or doesn't even exist, I'm not quite sure on that). The preview is always smaller (at least smaller than very large files).

The reason I didn't recognize this earlier is because for me this is happening on files marked as "offline". So the file should be there. For some reason Dropbox is not consistently syncing files marked as "offline". Sometimes when I restart Finder or the computer it will recognize this and sync the files, but usually no.

I'm still looking for solutions to Dropbox problems, but not nearly my highest priority.

I hope this helps somebody else.

***--- original answer ---***

I found a solution in another post (after reading dozens). Restarting Finder did it, but restarting the computer didn't (weird). Restarting finder:

https://9to5mac.com/2019/01/18/restart-finder-mac/

> 1. Use the keyboard shortcut command + option + escape
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the Force Quit Applications list
> 3. Click Finder
> 4. Click Relaunch in the bottom right corner of the window